# ruby linkedin gem permissions

Tags: ruby, linkedin-api

I am trying to use the ruby linkedin gem - https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.  I am just playing around with plain ruby (not rails)

If I follow the example given with the gem, I can get client.profile.  however when i try client.group_memberships or client.connections I get a 403 access denied.

I suspect the problem is related to permissions granted:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#toggleview:id=ruby

How do I set these options?
Is there anything else which might have gone wrong?

Comment: It would help if you showed the code you're using and the error returned.

Comment: I am using the code in the Usage section of the gem: https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin - see the part titled Authenticate.  All that is successful.  After that I try to use `client.group_memberships` or `client.connections`

Comment: Did you get a real consumer key and secret from your developer account on linkedin or did you use 'your_consumer_key' and 'your_consumer_secret' verbatim in the line: client = LinkedIn::Client.new('your_consumer_key', 'your_consumer_secret')?

Comment: :-) I got a real key.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Same issue here, any luck finding the problem?

Comment: there was a defect fix. I'll try to post it later.  I still cannot get it to work in the irb.  However, if you are using it in a web app it should work.  Check the gem repo for the fix

Comment: Here is the issue: https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin/pull/137  I am not very familiar with github or gems so not sure if this was integrated into the current version.  do let me know if you can figure out how to use it from the irb or cli